# Azure Alert Notifications not activated

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-management, sql-azure-alerts

I created alerts to notify us when our SQL Database DTU usage peaks, but the alerts are still in a "Not activated" status:

[image: Azure Alert Notifications]

The alert details are also showing a "Not activated" state:

[image: Azure Alert Details]

But the alerts are set to "Enabled":

[image: Azure Alert Enabled]

**How do I go about activating them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran across this same "issue" and found this thread. I use sarcastic quotes because I felt really dumb when I figured it out. Alerts will be "Activated" when the alert's condition is satisfied. So "Not Activated" is actually a good thing as long as the Alert is "Enabled." If you see "Disable Alert" at the bottom then you know it is enabled.

More info:
http://hypervking.info/alerting-and-notifications-support-for-windows-azure-applications/